# Managed Package record type not de

Tags: managed-package, salesforce1-app, record-type

I am getting some errors in a managed package. I am in a production environment. I have uninstalled Recon Managed Package. But I am facing some errors Like that:

Error: **Record Type**    ResourceThis installed component is referenced by a locally created component.

Am I missing any config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check on which object the record type "Resource" is linked with. There could be at least 1 record created in the org, with record type "Resource".

Try to delete the record(s) and also hard delete them from recycle bin.

Then try to uninstall managed package again